# Cross-platform way to register file type associations with Python

Tags: python, cross-platform, mime-types, file-type

Is there a platform-agnostic way to create file type associations with Python?

Looking for something which would provide a simple high-level API for creating and binding MIME types (e.g. `application/x-my-custom-type`) to file extensions (e.g. `*.egg`, `*.plant`), as well as registering/unregistering an app to handle the corresponding mime types.

There is nothing like this in the standard library, so I am looking for a module, or existing wrapper code, in order to avoid handing file associations separately for Linux, OSX, and Windows.

Comment: I am also looking for exactly this. I am convinced there must be a way to do this elegantly

Comment: I have been looking for something similar as well. I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html), but it is only for reading purposes. I am afraid the only way to create the bindings is doing it manually. Within Windows with `assoc` and `ftype`. Within linux maybe running some external bash script ([`xdg-mime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime)). I am not familiar with OSX. Let me know if you find any better solution please.